# Spring boot application cannot connect to the mongodb cluster , getting NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, database-connection

We are using Spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE.

Earlier we are using 4.0.21 - Following code worked with 4.0.21

```
@Bean
MongoClient mongoClient() {
    ....
    credentials.add(MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(username, "admin", mongoPas.toCharArray()));
    ---
    return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostname, port), credentials, options);
}
```

Now we migrated to MaaS 4.2.1 .
SCRAM-SHA-1 has been deprecated in our organization, all clusters will be updated to allow only SCRAM-SHA-256 during the upgrade during the Maas 4.0 to 4.2 upgrade.

Using mongo compass we can connect to our mongodb databse but not through application.

We need createScramSha256Credential to connect to mongodb database. so did following code change

```
credentials.add(MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(username, "admin", mongoPas.toCharArray()));
```

Note - spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency already added in pom.xml

& Added 2 new dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
             <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
             <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
             <version>3.12.8</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
             <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
             <version>3.12.7</version>
         </dependency>
```

Not getting compilation error but while starting application. Getting following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(Lcom/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ServerSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory;Lcom/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory;Ljava/util/List;Lcom/mongodb/event/ClusterListener;Lcom/mongodb/event/ConnectionPoolListener;Lcom/mongodb/event/ConnectionListener;Lcom/mongodb/event/CommandListener;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mongodb/client/MongoDriverInformation;)Lcom/mongodb/connection/Cluster;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(Lcom/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ServerSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings;Lcom/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory;Lcom/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory;Ljava/util/List;Lcom/mongodb/event/ClusterListener;Lcom/mongodb/event/ConnectionPoolListener;Lcom/mongodb/event/ConnectionListener;Lcom/mongodb/event/CommandListener;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mongodb/client/MongoDriverInformation;)Lcom/mongodb/connection/Cluster;
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:744) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:728) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:293) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:288) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:192) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.3.jar:na]
    at com.company.myapp.configs.MongoConfig.mongoClient(MongoConfig.java:70) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Could you add this to your pom.cml file and rebuild again:
 `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
 </dependency>`

Comment: @nouhero spring-boot-started-data-mongodb  already added.